# Google Colab: Your session crashed for an unknown reason

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using some modelling software on Google Drive, importing the necessary python libraries for the work I'm doing and running the 3rd party software (model builder). There hasn't ever been an issue in the first two parts of this, only when running the software.

Sometimes, it crashes when I start the model builder and sometimes it crashes after some iterations (the modeling software is running anywhere from 30-1000 times depending on what type of model I'm building). So, sometimes it completes the job (as it lasts enough iterations) and other times it doesn't.

I've had the same model as this run without issue before, and I've only changed one parameter in the model, which I can't see being the cause of this error.

I understand that the error and some of the information here is quite vague, however any input on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### Update

The less populated my Google Drive is the more the code progresses, however I am only using 20% of my storage and still having these problems.

Comment: You're right when you say the info you give here is quite vague - we don't know what "the software" is, how you're running it, how the code looks, how the data looks... and the error message, one of the few inputs given, is as vague as they come. I don't know much about this part of Colab, but I can bet having as much info as possible (and, who knows, a reproducible example?) would get you much better answers, in a much smaller time frame.

Comment: Due to an agreement I cant disclose much information. The software is a geophysics modeling software. The software is being run using a CUDA GPU (this has worked in the past), the software code is python and c++, and has worked previously, I cant really show it here as it is several 1000 lines of code.

Comment: That's better info, and the reason for the lack of disclosure is fair. I hope folks here will be able to help you faster now.